# How to display graphical text without X using C?

Tags: c, opengles, framebuffer

Using the Raspberry Pi 2 with the official 7" touchscreen, I want to display some high quality text without using an Xorg server.  I'm looking for APIs that provide simple functions such as:

```
Render_text ("hello", x,y, blue, size, "nicefontX");
```

Such a library could be build on top of the linux kernel framebuffer or openGLES/VG.  I have found at least [one such thing that appears to be pi specific](https://github.com/ajstarks/openvg).

Again, I am interested in C -- I have already found many things involving python.

Comment: Zogger -> I think I may have been wrong about not referring to this as the framebuffer, since everything that does this seems to require it be built into the kernel  -- all apologies.  But I'm still sure I'm right about the fact that you will find much more material here if you search beyond "raspberry pi".  Anyway, good luck.

Comment: BTW, I can't provide a complete answer, but it looks to me like [SDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer) runs on the Pi using the framebuffer -- although again examples of its use won't be pi specific (if you keep waiting for that, you are going to be waiting a long time, honestly).  Anyway, I am pretty sure it does have text features, although it has been 6-7 years since I used it.

Answer (score 4):

Did you consider 2D Game engines/libraries ? Because OpenGL/OpenVG are very low-level and don't do font handling , the added "belt and suspenders" of those libs will make your life much easier :

http://www.raylib.com/

https://github.com/raysan5/raylib

Answer (score 1):

I got 2D vector graphics library working, using it from C Language, currently with a 128x128 OLED display on a *headless* Raspberry Pi 3B, using the following recipe.  Note: X-Windows (X11) is *not* installed (e.g. Raspian lite edition).  As for performance considerations, OpenVG's claim to fame is that it utilizes available HW acceleration layer(s) rather than just load the CPU.

1. Install: Raspian lite edition
2. Install: [fbcp-ili9341](https://github.com/juj/fbcp-ili9341): "Blazingly fast display driver for SPI-based LCD displays for Raspberry Pi A,B,2,3, and Zero"

   I built that from source, and configured the the GPIO pins SPI pins via the (documented) -D commands on the compiler line.  For example:

   ```
   # cmake -DSSD1351=ON -DGPIO_TFT_DATA_CONTROL=25 -DGPIO_TFT_RESET_PIN=24 -DSPI_BUS_CLOCK_DIVISOR=30 -DARMV8A=ON \  ..
   ```

   and then proved it work sanity tested it by writing stuff to /dev/fb0.
3. Didn't need to install OpenGL libraries on my Raspian systems, because they seemed to be pre-installed at /opt/vc/lib, opt/vc/include.

   However,  I created the following symlinks:

   ```
   # cd /opt/vc/lib
   # ln -s libbrcmGLESv2.so libGLESv2.so
   # ln -s libbrcmEGL.so libEGL.so
   ```
4. [OpenVG](https://www.khronos.org/openvg/) "The Standard for Vector Graphics Acceleration"

   ```
   https://github.com/ajstarks/openvg
   ```
5. Compiled the following C program and ran it. Worked perfectly.

   ```
   $ cc -o demo demo.c -I/opt/vc/include -Lopt/vc/lib -lshapes

   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stddef.h>
   #include <stdint.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include "VG/openvg.h"
   #include "VG/vgu.h"
   #include "fontinfo.h"
   #include "shapes.h"

   int main() {
       int width, height;
       char s[3];

       init(&width, &height);                  // Graphics initialization
       Start(width, height);                   // Start the picture
       Background(0, 50, 0);                   // Black background
       Fill(44, 77, 232, 1);                   // Big blue marble
       Circle(width / 2, 0, width);            // The "world"
       Fill(255, 255, 255, 1);                 // White text
       TextMid(width / 2, height / 2, 
           "hello, world", 
            SerifTypeface, width / 10);        // Greetings 
       End();                                  // End the picture
       fgets(s, 2, stdin);                     // look at the pic, end with [RETURN]
       finish();                               // Graphics cleanup
       exit(0);
   }
   ```

[image]

[image]